# CSS : get a button overlapped by a div,z-index not working

Tags: html, css, z-index

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mqw0fqn1/)

Can anyone figure out how to get the button overlapped by `flyout-content` so that the right border of the button is hidden ? I want to get this effect:

[image]

I have tried changing the `z-index` of the content and the button, however it doesn't work.

### HTML

```
<div class='flyout'>
  <button class="flyout-toggle">Click</button>
  <div class="flyout-content"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.flyout-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    top: 50%;
    left: -50px;
    z-index: 998;
    width: 85px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #92C7B8;
    border: solid #fff 1px;
}
.flyout-content {
    z-index:997
}
.flyout {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: solid #fff 1px;
    background: #92C7B8;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -5px 15px 0px #bfbfbf;
    box-shadow: 0px -5px 15px 0px #bfbfbf;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `display:block` to the button

Answer (score 5):

jus add this `border:none;`

```
.flyout-toggle {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #92c7b8;
    border: medium none;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 35px;
    left: -50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    width: 85px;
    z-index: 998;
}
```

but if you need a border you can add it where you need ie border-top border-left border-right; like this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GheKi)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `border-top: none` and `outline: none`:

```
.flyout-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    top: 50%;
    left: -60px;
    z-index: 998;
    width: 85px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #92C7B8;
    border: solid #fff 1px;
    border-top: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mqw0fqn1/4/)

Answer (score 0):

The `z-index` elements must be on the same level. In your situation, the `flyout` has the biggest `z-index` but he is the parent of `flyout-toggle` which has a smaller one.

Try like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <button class="flyout-toggle">Click</button>
    <div class="flyout"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
    height:100%;
    width: 15%;
}
```

Now I put the `position:fixed` styles to the `parent`, not its child `flyout`.

[Check the full fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqw0fqn1/2), you'll notice that the right side of the button can't be clicked on because `flyout` is over it.

Answer (score -1):

in .flyout-toogle change

```
z-index: 998; to z-index: -1.
```

> [check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrg1j8k8/3/)

Comment: z-index to `-1` has other negativate effects like not being able to click the button and hover effects not working